# ASIHTTPRequest setTemporaryFileDownloadPath: not working with some URL's

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, url, asihttprequest

When I download a URL like this one: http://tinyurl.com/csr2xc7 then ASIHTTPRequest's temporaryFile is created and the data is not stored in memory. However with a URL like this: http://www.youtube-mp3.org/get?video_id=2MDYBFKjx2I&h=03492626150e7377f6def57cd3bdc16d the temporary file is not created.

The difference is that the second URL immediately starts a download when you open it, whereas the first URL only displays a video that can be downloaded using a request. Also when you open the second url you are first redirected before the download starts.

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it myself. When the original request is redirected the temporary file gets deleted too. So in the `request:willRedirectToURL:` you simply have to set the path again, and now its working like a charm :)

```
- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)orig willRedirectToURL:(NSURL *)newURL {
    NSArray *ar = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library..."];
    [request setDownloadDestinationPath:[[ar objectAtIndex:orig.tag] valueForKey:@"Path"]];
    [request setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:[[ar objectAtIndex:orig.tag] valueForKey:@"tmp"]];
    [request redirectToURL:newURL];
}
```