# ASIHttpRequest - Not creating temp file after moving to live PHP server

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, asihttprequest

I am facing this weird problem. On tapping a button I'm downloading media files such as image, video, and audio from my PHP Server. For the downloading part I use `ASIHTTPRequest`.

I use this code for resuming the download:

```
NSString *audio_url_f = [myDetailPeom poem_audio_url];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:audio_url_f];

ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];

[request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
[request setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:3];
[request setDelegate:self];
        //
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@",NSHomeDirectory(),fileName];
path = [path stringByAppendingString:@".download"];   

// This file has part of the download in it already
[request setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:path];
[request setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:YES];
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:filePath];

//
[request setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"audio" forKey:@"type"]];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

If the network fails the download stops and resumes properly. The partially downloaded file is created in the location properly with `.download` appended in its filename. Once the network is available, it resumes the downloading properly.

Now I moved my web app to the live PHP server (both are on the same server). But the partial file is not created at all.

Comment: not regarding your problem, but consider switching to other frameworks like `AFNetworking`. `ASIHTTP` is no longer maintained/supported by author

Answer (score 0):

Highly unlikely unless you have done a mistake in the URL. One common mistake done most of the time is when moving to a live server if its HTTPS this should be properly handled in ASI. If so try setting setValidatesSecureCertificate to NO.

AS ASIHttpRequest is deprecated you should consider moving to AFNetworking or RestKit or some other framework based on your need.

Comment: Actually the live server is not HTTTPS.

Comment: Were you able to debug this?

Comment: I tried my best,when connecting to the live server it is not creating the .download file at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to get document directory instead?

```
NSString *documentDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

NSString *path= [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.download"];
```

Its always better to use Cache directory for this instead the document directory.

Answer (score 0):

Can this happen in your scenario?

[ASIHTTPRequest setTemporaryFileDownloadPath: not working with some URL's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673547/asihttprequest-settemporaryfiledownloadpath-not-working-with-some-urls)

Check this whether it redirects.